# How do i register a security key (for windows log-in) for my regular Microsoft accounts?

Tags: windows, azure, azure-active-directory, fido-u2f, fido

To break the problem down, all I am trying to do is use a security key (FIDO2 security key) with my Microsoft account (hotmail) to log into my PC. Does anyone know how I can best do this?

**Details of my attempt using Azure AD:**

I have an AAD tenant where security keys have been enabled for all users. When creating a user in AAD, setting up the key for that user in http://myprofile.microsoft.com/ and then AAD joining my PC, I can login to my PC with the registered security key to that particular account.

However, if I invite an external user with a regular "@outlook" or "@hotmail" account to my AAD, I cant login to http://myprofile.microsoft.com/ since this user is not added to the "Microsoft Services" tenant and can not access application '19db86c3-b2b9-44cc-b339-36da233a3be2'(My Access). Instead I tried setting up the security key in account.microsoft.com for microsoft accounts.

Since my PC is AAD joined with the AAD user, the security option is there during login and with that I tried signing in to my "@hotmail" account on my PC with the security key I set up for that account. That seemed to initially work until it finally said "You can't sign in with this account. Try another account"

Does anyone know how to set up security keys for regular microsoft accounts or how to possibly add an external to the 'Microsoft Services' tenant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently only work or school account is supported for azure ad joined devices. The guest Microsoft account is not supported.

If you have a pc which is not azure ad joined you can login to that pc with Microsoft account. You can check the detailed information from this [article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2018/11/20/sign-in-to-your-microsoft-account-without-a-password-using-windows-hello-or-a-security-key/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately the link you shared is how to set it up with your Microsoft accounts for login to online Microsoft services and not for Windows PC login.